# High idle in wet conditions

Tags: electrical, acceleration, fuel-injection

I have a Lexmoto adrenaline and it works fine in the dry most of the time until recently. It starts to idle significantly higher in the rain and on off acceleration when trying to speed up. I have no idea why it does this. I've tried WD40'ing any electrical I can see and this has worked a couple times. Now wd40 just doesn't work. I'm super confuze and frustrated with this. Can anyone help or recommend anything

Comment: You could try smearing anything electrical with petroleum jelly.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Agree with @SteveMatthews, though I'd use dielectric grease instead of PJ.